# Proof that $C([-1,1])$ not complete

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, complete-spaces

I need help with the following exercise, leading to the conclusion that $X := C([-1,1])$ (space of continuous functions $f: [-1,1] \to \mathbb R$) equipped with the $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$-norm is not complete:

> For each $n\in \mathbb N$, define $\delta_n : X \to \mathbb C$ by 
>   $$\delta_n(f) := \frac{n}{2} \int_{-1/n}^{1/n}f(x)\,dx.$$
>   Prove:
>   1) $\delta_n \in X'$ for each $n\in \mathbb N$ and $\lVert \delta_n \rVert = \frac{n}{2}$ (the last norm is the operator norm).
>   2) $\delta_\infty : X \to \mathbb C, \delta_\infty(f) := f(0)$ does not define a bounded linear functional on $X$.
>   3) $\lim_{n \to \infty} \delta_n(f) = f(0) $ for all $ f \in X$.
>   4) $X$ is not complete.

Attempt:
1) To show that $\delta_n(f)$ is bounded is straight forward. However, how do I compute the operator norm? I showed $$\lVert \delta_n \rVert \leq \frac{n}{2}$$
but how do I get equality?
2) I tried to find a bounded sequence $f_n$ for which $(\delta_\infty(f_n))_n$ is unbounded, but couldn't think of something that worked out.
3) No problems here.
4) How does this follow from the other points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

1) See 2.

2) Use a function which graph is a pointed hat having height $n$ and basis $\frac{2}{n}$

4) If $X$ is a Banach space, the [uniform boundedness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle) applies to the sequence $\delta_n$

Comment: I tried using something like $$f_n(x) := -n^2x + n \quad x \in [0, 1/n] \\ f_n(x) := n^2x + n \quad x \in [-1/n, 0[$$. Then $$\delta_n(f_n) = \frac{n}{2}$$ for each $n\in \mathbb N$, but the 1-norm isn't 1... Never mind, it suffices to look at $n=1$, right? Is my function the correct one?

Comment: @lappen68 Of course the $1$-norm is $1$. The area below the curve of $f_n$ is twice the area of a triangle with base $\frac{1}{n}$ and height $n$. This is the correct function.

Comment: I figured it out now. Thanks for your help. As for 4): assuming $X$ was Banach and applying the Uniform Boundedness Principle, we get that $\sup_{n\in \mathbb N}\lVert \delta_n \rVert < \infty$, a contradiction to 1).